# Python regular expression problem with greedy

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-greedy

I'm following an online course, and I have problem with regular expression.

From "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Anayah.html"
I'd like to extract only "Anayah"

This is my try:

```
stringToParse = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Anayah.html, we just want Anayah"
print(re.search(r'[_](\w+)\.html', stringToParse).group(1))
```

This returns "by_Anayah" so the "by_" part in giving me some problems...

I know about ? for being non-greedy, but wherever I try to insert ?, I never get what I want.

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `\w` also matches `_` chars. Replace `\w` with `[^\W_]` that matches all word chars except underscores.

Use

```
import re
stringToParse = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Anayah.html, we just want Anayah"
print(re.search(r'_([^\W_]+)\.html', stringToParse).group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/n3q12e) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vjw494/1).

Comment: Thank you ! Can I push my luck and ask you what would be the difference between your answer and : <code>r'_([^_]+)\.html'

Comment: It may be `[^_]`. It all depends on the requirements.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to write... I'm fighting/learning the comment format system